# How can Puppeteer's uploadFile work on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate the task of downloading mp3 files from a web site and uploading to another web site. With Puppeteer, I'm able to do this with the following code.

```
// ... Download the file and save locally
// Sets the value of the file input to fileToUpload
inputUploadHandle.uploadFile(fileToUpload);
// ... submit the form
```

This works fine on my Mac. I can download the file and upload it through the form submit. When I deployed it on Heroku, I'm aware that Heroku's ephemeral file system will save the file to /app folder. And I'm even able to send that saved file through NodeMailer as an attachment.

But on my Heroku app, when Puppeteer submit the form, the file is not uploaded as it should be. The submit happens as if the file is not selected.

I know I can have work arounds like grabbing the file from my own server. But I'm still curious why this happens. What makes Puppeteer uploadFile to fail on Heroku?

By the way, here are two links that might help with the background:

1. [Practical Puppeteer: How to upload a file programmatically](https://dev.to/sonyarianto/practical-puppeteer-how-to-upload-a-file-programatically-4nm4)
2. [puppeteer-heroku-buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack)

Answer (score 0):

The solution: if you want to use uploadFile, don't use Puppeteer version 2.1.1, for now stick to 2.0.0. In your package.json:

```
"puppeteer": "2.0.0"
```

I checked recently and found out that uploadFile is still broken in Puppeteer 5.5.0.

Here's the detail. When I develop on my Mac, I didn't specify a version for puppeteer. But I happened to be using a version in which uploadFile works. However, every time you push to Heroku, Heroku will check your package.json to install all dependencies. In my case, Heroku updated to the latest version (by the time of this writing 2.1.1) which broke the uploadFile function.

Even though I printed out the Chromium version early on and noticed that Heroku is using a higher version, it never occurred to me that I should test with an older version of Puppeteer. Instead, I spent a lot of time testing other workarounds, which all failed. Any way, once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth.

I'll post an issue on Puppeteer and hope this to be fixed in the next release.